# PostgreSQL find inconsistency record in the row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table as below:

```
   PO Num  |  Salesman |   Phone   |  
-----------+-----------+-----------+
 PO13175   |  Sarah    |  111      |
 PO13203   |  Sarah    |  1111     |  
 PO12203   |  Tom      |  222      |  
 PO8656    |  Tom      |  222      |  
...
(n rows)
```

The Salesman and Phone numbers are in pair and how can I identify the discrepancy like Number 2 Row? (Sarah should have a consistent phone number like Tom does)

I have tried to use "partition"

```
select *,Row_number() over (partition by Salesman,Phone) as row from table
where row>1;
```

But it didn't give me what I wanted.

I wanted to get the record as below:

```
   PO Num  |  Salesman |   Phone   |  
-----------+-----------+-----------+
 PO13175   |  Sarah    |  111      |
 PO13203   |  Sarah    |  1111     |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could query the results with a simple group by / having, too:

```
select salesman
from sales
group by salesman
having count(distinct phone) > 1
```

Comment: This is the most simple and easy way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

You were along the right lines with Windowing function.
The following will return Sarah as having inconsistent phone number

```
select a.*
from
(select 
salesman
,phone
,count(*) as freq
,count(*)over(partition by salesman order by phone) as distinct_phone_num_id
from mydata /*replace this with your actual tablename*/
group by 
salesman
,phone) as a
inner join
(select distinct salesman from mydata) as b
on a.salesman=b.salesman and a.distinct_phone_num_id>1
;
```

Explanation:
The `a` table will first count all possible `salesman` & `phone` combinations. Then `count(*)over(partition by salesman order by phone)` will serially enumerate each distinct phone number found for each salesman.

```
SALESMAN PHONE FREQ DISTINCT_PHONE_NUM_ID 
Sarah   111     1   1 
Sarah   1111    1   2 
Tom     222     2   1
```

So, above you can see that `DISTINCT_PHONE_NUM_ID` says Sarah has upto 2 phone numbers and Tom has only 1 distinct number.

The purpose of the `inner join` is to give you a list of `salesman` with inconsistent phone numbers.

Final output:

```
SALESMAN PHONE FREQ DISTINCT_PHONE_NUM_ID 
Sarah   1111    1   2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl t1
JOIN tbl t2
  ON (t1.salesman = t2.salesman AND t1.phone <> t2.phone AND t1.po_num <> t2.po_num)
GROUP BY t1.salesman;
```

Would be interesting if that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM lutser_table lt
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM lutser_table ex
   WHERE ex.Salesman = lt.Salesman
   AND ex.Phone <> lt.Phone
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should NORMALIZE your database schema to avoid this kind of issues:

```
select * from t as t1
where EXISTS(select 1 from t 
                where t.salesman=t1.salesman 
                  and t.phone<>t1.phone)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6501c/1)

Answer (score 0):

select * from x where Salesman in(select salesman
from table_name
group by salesman
having count(distinct phone) > 1)

i hope this will give